# rollupjs doesn't update the new changes

Tags: reactjs, storybook, rollupjs

I have a customized library of components that uses rollup js to pass it to the main project.

The version i am using is 2.79.1

Whenever I update the package.json or add a new package it will not pass the most recent changes to my main project.

Here are some example when this occur:

- My lib has storybook also and when i need to test my local storybook i need to do "yarn add react react-dom" command in order to execute it. The storybook works fine. When i don't need to use the storybook anymore, i run the command "yarn remove react react-dom". With this done I try to pass the current changes locally to my main project and nothing is updated.
- I need to update Datepickers from Material UI, so i run the command "yarn add @mui/x-date-pickers". I try to pass this change to my main project and nothing happens.

On the console nothing appears to tell whats wrong. All seems to work fine but the most recent changes are not updated to the main project.

This is the command line of my main project:
[image]

This is the command line of my components Library:
[image]

It seems like the necessary files are not passed to the main project.

Here are the files that are passed when i don't update the packages:
[image]

And here are the files when i update the package:

[image]

I don't know what causes this problem, and I don't know how to resolve them. I need to do this updates to the packages but it won't let me.

Did this happens to someone else? What did you do to resolve this problem?

Thank you!